# Can a Gnome Terminal profile use UTF-8 by default?

Tags: gnome, terminal, unicode

I am on an Ubuntu (I think) system. I **don't** have root, so I can't change the locale. I want to make my default terminal profile use UTF-8 by default. There should be a way to do this, either in the `.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal/` directory somewhere, or in a environment variable, or something. However, I can't seem to find it.

Edit with more details:

In a terminal, I have:

```
grid-unv55$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
grid-unv55$ gnome-terminal
```

When try to more a UTF document in that new terminal, I get:

```
\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd
\noise:bgspeech \ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd
```

Which appears on my screen as dots.  (the uffds were a cut and paste. I left the "\noise:bgspeech" in there so you could see that ascii cut and pasted correctly)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe that gnome-terminal will Just Work with UTF-8 is enabled in the shell, so all you need to do is enable *that*. Put

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

in `~/.bashrc` and there you go.

---

EDIT:

Okay, so, the answer is [currently you can't set this](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=108711). Gnome Terminal follows the current environment's LANG setting and uses the encoding for that as the default. So you need to get LANG to contain UTF-8 *before* gnome-terminal is launched. Setting this in `~/.bashrc` should do it — you'll just need to log out and log in again.

(Note that it's actually better to put this in `~/.bash_profile` so you can override it for subshells, but I'm not sure that bash is necessarily run as a login shell as part of setting up the Gnome environment. That's worth testing....)

Comment: doesn't appear to work.

Comment: Hmm. What is $LANG set to by default? Does putting that in your bashrc make it change?

Comment: C, and putting it in the bashrc made it change. Granted, I didn't log-out and log back in again, but I started a new terminal, and it started with UTF in the LANG (and the locale is set with UTF as well) but the terminal still doesn't show Japanese...

Comment: What *does* it show?

Comment: It shows dots. Which, for some reason, cut and paste into firefox as \ufffd

Comment: In that case, I suspect that the system you are on simply doesn't have the right fonts.

Comment: It does, because when I manually change to utf-8 everything comes out fine!

Comment: Then I am way off base. :)

Comment: By "manually change to UTF-8" I mean that in the gnome-terminal menu, I select utf-8 encoding, as Richard mentioned.

Comment: Evidently, I needed to completely log out and back in again. Now the locale seems to have worked... I'm not sure why it didn't before, but whatever.

Comment: Before, it was only getting set in the shell _inside_ gnome-terminal. Now, it's getting set in the environment under which gnome-terminal itself runs.

Comment: I thought that if I explicitly ran terminal from a shell that had locale set, then it would start a new process. evidently, it tried to outsmart me. I *HATE* it when computers try to be "helpful". arg... thanks.

Comment: gnome-terminal defaults to using *one* process in which all the windows run, in order to save resources. So that's how it was tricking you there.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out AFTER the fact... B-/

Comment: Under Ubuntu 10.04, you can set environment variables for the whole session from `~/.profile` — [not `~/.bashrc`](http://askubuntu.com/questions/13077/is-profile-sourced-by-bash/13182#13182), and [not `~/.bash_profile` either](http://superuser.com/questions/183845/which-setup-files-should-be-used-for-setting-up-environment-variables-with-bash/183956#183956).

Answer (score 9):

You can set the locale for `gnome-terminal` with the following command where `Default` is the name of the profile.

```
gconftool --set --type=string /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/encoding en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: This worked for me.  But was unnecessary after changing `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` in `.bashrc` and restarting

Comment: Worked great for me!

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem, and when setting `LANG` in `.bash_profile` didn't do the trick, I found out that in Gnome, the default locale can be set at the beginning of a session from the GDM login screen. This can be done without root access.

Answer (score 3):

I just checked in `menu->terminal->set character encoding` it is utf-8

## The terminal and bash are not the same thing.

I would start by doing `cat utf-8-file` (cat and bash will pass this file unchanged to the terminal, (well actually to stty, stty will convert newline to carrage return, newline etc.)) if this displays the file properly then gnome-terminal is setup. (This so far is all I have ever done, as I use utf-8 in english; it was already set up in Ubuntu 10.10 and Debian 6 for me). So then just to set up bash etc.

## Re-reading ~/.bashrc

If you edit `~/.bashrc` you must re-read it `. ~/.bashrc` (or start a new shell) (dont forget the dot)

Comment: When I manually change the character encoding to utf-8, that's where I do it, but when I start a new gnome-terminal, even from a terminal that has the correct locale, the encoding is still ascii. I'll add more details to the question.

Answer (score 3):

I had an issue just now that I fixed that may be relevant for new-comers with newer versions of GNOME (and gnome-terminal):

For any text encoding you want to use, the shell (e.g. bash) and terminal emulator (e.g. gnome-terminal) must use the same encoding. So e.g. if the shell uses `en_US.utf8` and the terminal emulator uses `en_US.ISO-8859-1` (a.k.a. `latin1`), then you will see strange text in your terminal for any program with UTF-8 output.

Now, I am not able to set the encoding upon login, as I've seen suggested would be possible. This might be due to the fact that we have an older version of GDM here at work. This is why I've needed a different solution.

Anyway, GNOME 3 doesn't seem to automatically source `.bashrc` nor `.profile` upon login. But it does source `.gnomerc`, in which you can put environment variables that will be exported to GNOME programs (as far as I can tell).

Putting `export LANG="en_US.utf8"` in `.gnomerc` thus starts gnome-terminal using a UTF-8 encoding by default, when a new instance is started. (Change your locale according to your needs.)

Hopefully this has been useful to someone!

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned by other users, tell the shell which encoding you're using with

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Put this in .bashrc and gnome-terminal *should* pick it up on the next login.

Set the encoding for gnome-terminal on the fly:  **Menubar > Terminal > Set Character Encoding**

Set default encoding permanently: **gconf-editor > Apps > gnome-terminal > Profiles > Default > encoding > utf-8**

Comment: This isn't quite true.  For me, I have a .profile and a .bashrc file.  My login shell is bash.  gnome-terminal ignores LANG settings in .bashrc if it conflicts with LANG settings in .profile.  So, LANG needs to be set in both files.

Comment: Sort of … my understanding is that bash uses **.profile** for login shells, and **.bashrc** otherwise. On Linux, new command windows use **.bashrc** (on Mac, it's **.profile**). I'm unaware of any circumstances where both would be run automatically, but it is extremely common to put all your configuration into one and then call it from the other. Typically, **.bashrc** is run from **.profile** (typically only from interactive shells). `if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" -a -f "$HOME/.bashrc"; then . "$HOME/.bashrc"; fi`