# UTF-8 works in gnome-terminal only after selecting already selected encoding

Tags: gnome-terminal, character-encoding

Running Centos 6.3. In gnome-terminal UTF-8 works, but only after I've chosen (the already chosen) UTF-8 encoding in gnome-terminal settings.

How do I force gnome-terminal to respect its own encoding setting?

Comment: I don't know, but try `urxvt` instead of `gnome-terminal`. It is faster (the "r" is for reduced resources) and, as for your problem, the "u" is for Unicode :)

Comment: Do you have a simple testcase anyone else can try? I suspect most people using CentOS 6 think their Gnome Terminal works just fine with Unicode. A good example would be a bit of text inserted into your question that, when pasted into a local file and `cat`ted, doesn't show up right.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem. I fixed it by adding `export LANG="en_GB.utf8"` to `~/.bashrc` and then logged out to restart my X window session.

Use `locale -a | grep -i utf8` from the command-line to get a list of locales with UTF-8 support.

I think the problem is that Gnome Terminal will automatically disable UTF-8 support if it doesn't detect it in your locale environment variables.

Comment: There is a more complete explanation at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/8859/5132 .