# how to make terminal utf-8

Tags: bash, terminal, unicode

How can I make my terminal(bash) window uft-8, that it can show utf-8 characters?

my operating system is : ubuntu 12.04 my desktop : gnome-shell

How about native shell(outside of desktop)?

Comment: I would be very surprised if, in a normal install of any version of Ubuntu, it wasn't already UTF-8. What is the output of `locale -c charmap`? If it says `LC_CTYPE` and `UTF-8` you should be already good. If not, you need to set your locale to something (like `en_US.UTF-8`) that uses UTF-8

Comment: - what is the terminal emulator?
- what are the current locales? (output of `locale -a`)

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8859/can-a-gnome-terminal-profile-use-utf-8-by-default) question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bash for example you can use UTF-8 like this:

```
echo $'\xe2\x95\xb1'
```

which prints this:

```
╱
```

Or you can use Unicode characters like this:

```
echo -e "\U2571"
```

which prints this:

```
╇
```

Comment: This is the answer to _How can I print something in UTF-8?_ whereas the question asked, as written, was how make a terminal (correctly) show something that was output in UTF-8.